# SQL Recursion with row_numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, window-functions, row-number

I got a temporary view in PostgreSQL which offers the following data (simplified):

```
temporary_view (sum, rw):

|sum   |  rw|
|1337  |   1|
|42    |   2|
|...   | ...|
```

Now I need to do a recursion on this until my condition is reached.

For simplicity, let's say I want to calculate, how many rows I need to get a `sum > 2000`.
In my real implementation I need to use a far more complicated formula.

If the `sum > 2000` is reached, the recursion should stop and return the last row_number used for the calculation.

How would you implement this in SQL? I tried a lot of things but unfortunately I fail every time.

My thoughts: I would use a temporary view with `(sum, row, last_row)` where I decrement last_row every time but unfortunately I'm struggling with the implementation ...

Comment: Postgres has recursive CTEs

Comment: Well I know about the temporary views ;)

Comment: It's bad form to change the question after a valid answer has been given. Ask a new question if it turns out you need something different. And don't use `row` as column name. It's a reserved word. Not even in dummy code - it's hard to work with an illegal setup.

Comment: sorry - changed it back and going to open a new question with more thoughts :(

Comment: Changed the column name to `rw` in accordance with the answer. And please always state your version of Postgres. Possible solutions may depend on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select min(rw)
from
(
    select rw, sum(sm) over(order by rw) sm_cum
    from temporary_view
)
where sm_cum > 2000;
```

Use analytic functions to calculate a cumulative sum then get the min rw. You don't even need a recursion here.

Recursive variant for sum (you can change it on your expression):

```
with recursive tmp (rw, complicated) as (
    select rw, sm
    from temporary_view where rw = 1 and sm <= 1000
    union 
    select t.rw, tmp.complicated + t.sm
    from temporary_view t join tmp on t.rw = tmp.rw + 1
    where tmp.complicated <= 1000
)
select max(rw) from tmp;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/11583/3

Comment: Thanks for this very fast answer! This seems very easy to use. Unfortunately I have simplified my problem too much as this probably wouldn't work for my needs. I'm going to modify my question. Thanks and sorry!

Comment: @Frame91 I've added the recursive variant. You can try to change some expressions to reach what you need.

Answer (score 1):

For the original question: to get the whole row, not just the value of `rw`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, sum(sm) OVER(ORDER BY rw) sum_sm
   FROM   temporary_view
)
WHERE  sum_sm > 2000  -- you may really want >=
ORDER  BY sum_sm
LIMIT  1;
```